# Sharepoint 2010 Read Only problem mode

Tags: sharepoint-server

[image]i am getting an error on SharePoint 2010 all user getting “ready only documents”.

Server

Windows Server 2008 R2 > SharePoint 2010 Windows Server 2008 R2 > SQL server 2010 User run on Citrix

- Windows 7, IE and Office 2013

No success with below suggestion :(

- Trusted sites in your IE
- go to Central Administration - Application Management - Change Quotas and Locks. If Read Only Is checked

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92555cd3-e66f-4788-b119-c85570f9817b/sharepoint-2010-read-only-problem?forum=sharepointadminprevious

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2013/05/06/set-sharepoint-content-database-in-read-only-mode/

Any help welcome.

Technet Link - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7abf5bde-0c2d-4c9c-b46f-5519cdb6f7b4/sharepoint-2010-read-only-problem-mode?forum=sharepointadminprevious&prof=required

Comment: Could you please describe the error message a little more? Also a Screenshot would help to understand your situation.

Comment: @MHeld i don't get any error message but I have uploaded an image

Comment: Does this happen to all users and all documents? Do users open the documents via InternetExplorer, via Open-in-Explorer or via OneDrive-Sync?

Comment: yes, this happens to all users and all documents 
users open via IE (i have change alot of setting in IE and Regfile) but no luck.

Comment: @MHeld any help?

Comment: No help but some tipps for further troubleshooting: Check SharePoint ULS-Log, maybe an error is logged there. Maybe a Fiddler-Trace on the client will also unveil something unusual.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "Edit Workbook" can you then edit the file?
Try enabling check-in / check-out in one document library to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: Hi Josh, after enabling check-in / check-out in one document library. i get this error (we can't do that for you because the file is no longer checked out )

Answer (score 0):

It is by designer that Office 2013 opening all documents as 'read only' from Sharepoint 2010.

Go to your document library's Settings, then click Advanced Settings. Find the option for "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents", and select "Open in the client application".

When a user open the document with office 2013, here is what that should look like:

[image]

You can click edit to open document in edit mode.